# Google Keep stopped sending push notifications on Android

Tags: google-keep

After about 2 or 3 months of using Google Keep I've noticed it does not notify me of due reminders any more (neither in Android nor in Chrome).  The only thing that I may think of that could have caused this -- I've disabled notifications "from this page" in Chrome.  But how could that have affected Android push?...

Does anyone know how to turn it back on?  On Android I mean.

UPD: I don't use any integrations (like Google Now) for these reminders -- plain Google Keep functionality.

UPD2: I double-checked.  Set up a reminder to fire in 5 minutes, than set down and watched what happens.  Turns out, it DOES play notification sound, and does show a reminder, in notifications bar, but only for a second, and then it disappears!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know whether this is a permanent and complete solution, and I don't know which one of the steps below are important or not, but -- I did the following steps, and now notifications seem to be working on my Android:

1. I went through and deleted all the notes that had reminders on them.
2. Opened Chrome settings -> advanced settings -> content settings -> notification settings -> manage exceptions.  Deleted exception for keep.google.com:443 from the list.
3. I had Keep opened as a tab in Chrome permanently, on a permanently running PC (windows).  I closed that tab.  If I need Keep on PC -- I'll need to open the page anew, do the edits, and close it again.  (The idea was that maybe the page being open did something to suppress notification somehow, or mark them "viewed" or something.)
4. Clear Keep application cache on Android. (Did *not* reinstall anything, did *not* delete all data -- just cache.)
5. Reboot Android.

It seems to be working for a few days now, haven't missed any notifications so far.